# Cross-binding checkboxes - isChecked #1 -> isEnabled #2

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have a ListBox that takes boolean elements from list in my model and represent them as checkboxes. Just after building project the second checkbox isEnabled is set to false. If I modify (eg. cut and paste same converter) binding in the second checkbox in debug, the binding start working correctly. Also I have a global checkboxes that modyfi isChecked properties of all checkboxes from listBox. If I set globalCheckbox #2, all listBox_checkBoxes #2 are set to true and all listBox_checkBoxes #1 isEnabled property are set to false

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_assent" SelectedIndex="-1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FullDataAssetList.List}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Height="Auto">
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="ListBoxItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Opacity="{Binding Path=SkipAssentTemp, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacity}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                <CheckBox  x:Name="chbx_Assent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ToolTip="Skip" IsChecked="{Binding SkipAssent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding SkipAssentTemp, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolean}}" LostFocus="chbx_Assent_LostFocus" Background="#FFCB0000"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text=" / "  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="chbx_AssentTemp" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ToolTip="Skip temp." IsChecked="{Binding SkipAssentTemp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsEnabled="{Binding SkipAssent, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolean}}" LostFocus="chbx_AssentTemp_LostFocus" Background="#FFCBA300"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(bool) || targetType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            if ((bool?)value == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            if ((bool?)value == false)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return null;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

 }
```

How can i fix binding to get full functionality just after building?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. DataTrigger in xaml was overwritnig isEnabled property